# How to download image to iPad programmatically?

Tags: java, javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I have some image files in server. I need to move or transfer the image files to iPad memory card, so that I can access the image files from the ipad memory card for my iPad application instead of hitting the server to load the image quickly.

My server side is using java.
My client side is using phonegap (javascript, html, css) for iPad.

In server side I am sending the response (response.setContentType("image/gif")) in image format. But I am not able to write image file in client side using javascript.

How to transfer image file to iPad memory storage?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just trying to download an image using in your Cordova application using Javascript?  I'm downloading PDFs to my app using the following code:

```
function downloadFileToPath(remoteUrl, localPath, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    if (!masseyApp.isInBrowser()) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(remoteUrl, localPath, 
            function(metadata) {

            console.log("Successfully downloaded " + remoteUrl + " to " + localPath + ".");

            if (successHandler) {
                successHandler(metadata);
            }

            }, 
            function (e) {
                errorHandler(error.createError(ERROR_IO_ERROR, "IO Error", "Failed to download " + e.source + " to " + e.target + " - " + fileErrorToString(e)));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Perhaps you can use this for your images.

Comment: while using ur code, the fileTransfer.download function is not called. its not working for me..

Comment: I didn't see this comment...I didn't notified. Did you solve the issue with FileTransfer.download()?

Comment: ya i have solved the issue. fileTransfer.download is working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consulted [the documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)?

*EDIT* You may have to use a plugin:  http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url

Comment: hi borrrden, thanks for ur reply.i have seen that plugin already.i am using cordova-1.6.0. the above plugin is using phonegap.js. so its saying that PGPlugin.h file is missing. i cant upgrade that plugin to cordova plugin. pl suggest me to how to do that.